# Does "hors mis" also mean except?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, prépositions

*Hors* means *outside* or *except*. I wonder if *hors mis* can also mean *except*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Hors* means outside or except."

The first use case for this preposition is "l’exclusion du lieu." i.e. "exclusion from a place" but it can also mean *excepté* (see [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hors)):

> *Ils y sont tous allés, **hors** deux ou trois*.
>  ***Hors** cela, je suis de
> votre sentiment*.

Here I would use the "locution prépositive" [*à part*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_part#Locution_pr%C3%A9positive) instead, because *hors* feels formal, archaic and may even be completely [outdated](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/does-hors-mis-also-mean-except/46527?noredirect=1#comment92812_46527) in such a context. There are many use cases where you have [*hors*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hors) in a [composition](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1002) with a noun to mean either outside a place or outside the scope of a thing.

---

"I wonder if *hors mis* can also mean except."

Since the 16th century (LBU14 § 259 H6) there is indeed a set composition from the past participle "hors mis" (a "lexicalisation du syntagme *hors mis*, participe passé de *mettre hors* « exclure »", [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/hormis)), and that's the preposition [*hormis*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hormis) which means *excepté, sauf*:

> *Il y a remède à tout, mon enfant, hormis à la mort* (Mérimée, in the
> TLFi)

---

The thing is even though we see both *hors* and *hormis* can share that *excepté* meaning, we still can't explain why in the last example I can't see *hors* ever being used whereas I would think *hormis* works just fine with the first two examples. The latter is really the one used for *excepté*. You can forget *hors mis* with two words, which is out of usage, and focus on *hormis*.

Comment: "Ils y sont tous allés, sauf deux ou trois" would be the most natural way of saying it (in my view).

Comment: @XouDo J'aurais probablement fait ce choix-là à l'écrit... Une chose est claire c'est que je n'aurais pas utilisé _hors_, je le trouve soutenu. Mais souvent quand j'ai jamais vu un truc je peux le voir comme soutenu. Bof.

Comment: Soutenu mais plus encore, désuet.  La valse des prépositions : *Sauf* se substitue à *hors* comme *hors* s'est substitué il y longtemps à *fors* qui lui-même avait remplacé *extra* en latin.

Comment: @XouDo *Ils sont tous morts, fors deux, ou trois*, *[Dictionnaire de l'Académie, 1re édition](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A1F0164)*, 1694.